# How to randomly display only even array indexes

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a math quiz for school. I am trying to use arrays of questions followed by answers, so that I can display a question and match the user answer with the expected answer. The problem I am having is the random numbers are totally random so I can't get just questions. I figured if I could accomplish that then the answer would be whatever index came up just with one added to it for the display answer. Here is my code so far for this class.

```
public class QuizQuestion {



String [] quesbank = {"2 + 3 =", "5", "5 x 2 =", "10"};

Random random = new Random();
String first;

public String getQuestion() {
    first = quesbank [random.nextInt(4)];

    return first;
}

public int getAnswer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Get random numbers from half the range you really want and then double them. That will guarantee that the number is even.

Answer (score 3):

Getting a random even number up to `n` is same as getting a random integer up to `n/2`, then doubling it.

A better solution if your task allows it is to split the array into two, one for questions, another parallel one for answers; or have an array of something that can hold both question and answers.

Comment: I thought about that but I'm kinda new to programming so I wasn't sure how to go about something like that.

Comment: `String[][] quesbank = {{"2 + 3 =", "5"}, {"5 x 2 =", "10"}};`; then you can do `quesbank[q][0]` for question `q`, and `quesbank[q][1]` for the corresponding answer, where `q` is `random.nextInt(quesbank.length)`. Making a class for Q/A pair would be better but a bit more advanced.

Comment: like this:                                                                                `String[][] quesbank = {{"2 + 3 =", "5"}, {"5 x 2 =", "10"}};`
 
     `Random q = new Random();`
     `String first;`
 
     `public String getQuestion() {`
     ` q.nextInt(quesbank.length);`
  
  `return quesbank[q][0];`
    ` }`

     ` public int getAnswer() {`
  
  `return quesbank[q][1];`
    ` }`

        ` }`